# Combine coherence tomography with second harmonic generation

Tags: optics, coherence

I was given the task to combine the OCT procedure with second harmonic generation. Problem is I am completely new to this stuff.

Could anyone give me a few proposals which I could use as starting points?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you read on how OCT and second harmonic generation work? There are entries on RP Photonics encyclopedia if you haven't (e.g. https://www.rp-photonics.com/optical_coherence_tomography.html)

Comment: Yes I do know the basics from both fields. But my knowledge is nowhere near close enough to be able to connect these.

Comment: to me the OP lacks details to move discussion any further. Assume you combine OCT and harmonic generation. What is it going to be used for?